# Simple ANN for Prediction Using 6-6-3 Network Architecture

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, prediction

I am a beginner looking to code an ANN in PyTorch for the task of prediction for a dynamic engineering system of a Free Piston Sterling Engine. The dataset consists of 6 inputs and 3 outputs, as shown below:
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liYap.png)

I have a basic code which I believe should be able to accommodate for this task, however I believe there may be an issue with the labelling of the dataset, and the datatype used. I have tried converting to longtensor datatype but it has not helped.

I receive the following error when changing the output datatype to float32:

"expected scalar type Long but found Float."

and when I put it as int64, I receive:

"Target 85 is out of bounds."

Please take a look, and any advice would be very appreciated. I have included the code below:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

SEED = 4096
torch.manual_seed(SEED)
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(SEED)
np.random.seed(SEED)

file_path = "./Dynamics of Sterling Engine Data(1).csv"
df = pd.read_csv(
    file_path,
    header=None,
    names=[
        "Kdp(N/m)",
        "Kpp(N/m)",
        "Cdp(Ns/m)",
        "Cl(Ns/m)",
        "mdp(kg)",
        "mpp(kg)",
        "f(Hz)",
        "γ(DP/PP)",
        "α(°)",
    ],
)

n = len(df.index)  # 55
shuffle_indices = np.random.permutation(n)
df = df.iloc[shuffle_indices]

x = df.iloc[:, :6].values.astype(np.float32)
y = df.iloc[:, -3].values.astype(np.float32)

mu = x.mean(axis=0)
span = x.max(axis=0) - x.min(axis=0)

def rescale(inputs):
    return (inputs - mu) / span
x = rescale(x)

num_train = int(n * 0.82)
num_test = n - num_train

x_train = x[:num_train]
y_train = y[:num_train]
x_test = x[-num_test:]
y_test = y[-num_test:]


class NpDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data, label):
        assert len(data) == len(label)

        self.data = torch.from_numpy(data)
        self.label = torch.from_numpy(label)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index], self.label[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.label)

train_dataset = NpDataset(x_train, y_train)
test_dataset = NpDataset(x_test, y_test)

train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=128, shuffle=False)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=128, shuffle=False)

device = torch.device("cpu")
print(device)

class SterlingNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SterlingNN, self).__init__()

        # 6 input feautures per data point
        self.fn1 = nn.Linear(6, 6)  # 6 features, 6 nodes in hidden layer
        self.fn2 = nn.Linear(6, 3)  # 6 nodes in hidden layer, 3 outputs

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.sigmoid(self.fn1(x))  # sigmoid activation function
        x = self.fn2(x)
        return x

model = SterlingNN()
print(model.to(device))

loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimiser = torch.optim.Adam(
    model.parameters(), lr=0.01, weight_decay=0.01
)

x, y = next(iter(train_dataloader))
x = x[:5].to(device)
score = model(x)
print(score)

def train():
    model.train()  # model into training mode and iteratate through data loader

    for x, y in train_dataloader:
        x = x.to(device)
        y = y.to(device)
        n = x.size(0)

        optimiser.zero_grad()
        score = model(x)
        loss = loss_fn(score, y)

        loss.backward()
        optimiser.step()

        predictions = score.max(1, keepdim=True)[1]
        num_correct = predictions.eq(y.view_as(predictions)).sum().item()

    acc = num_correct / n
    return loss, acc


def evaluate():
    model.eval()

    with torch.no_grad():
        for x, y in test_dataloader:
            x = x.to(device)
            y = y.to(device)
            n = x.size(0)

            score = model(x)
            loss = loss_fn(score, y)

            predictions = score.max(1, keepdim=True)[1]
            num_correct = predictions.eq(y.view_as(predictions)).sum().item()

    acc = num_correct / n
    return loss, acc

max_epochs = 128
for epoch in range(max_epochs):
    tr_loss, tr_acc = train()
    eva_loss, eva_acc = evaluate()

    print(
        "[{epoch}/{max_epochs}] Train loss:{tr_loss:.4f} acc:{tr_acc*100:.2f}% - Test loss:{eva_loss:.4f} acc:{eva_acc*100:.2f}%".format()
    )
```

Comment: Put the whole stacktrace of "Target 85 is out of bounds." here.

Comment: Your code seems fine.. But If you could give your dataset to try on then we could find the error. It might be a problem with your data.